# User-editable table with variable number of rows in Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm running Rails 3.2.11. I'm working on a simple wiki project as I learn Rails and Javascript. What I want to do is store a two-column table in my database whose contents and number of rows can be edited by users, and use jQuery to add forms for a new table row on a button click. The table is stored as a hash containing hashes for each row's columns. i.e. `{"row1" => {"head" => "first column/header content", "tail" => "second column/data content"}, "row2" => {"head" => "first column/header content", "tail" => "second column/data content"}}` The part of my _form.html.erb for editing the table looks like this:

```
<div id="node_table_row_0">
  <%= f.fields_for :table do |table_rows| %>
    <%= table_rows.fields_for :row do |table_cols| %>
      <%= table_cols.text_field :head, :id => 'node_table_row_head_0' %>
      <%= table_cols.text_field :tail, :id => 'node_table_row_tail_0' %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
  <button id="add_table_row" type="button" class="btn btn-small">Add Row</button>
</div>
```

I'm displaying the table on my page like so:

```
<table class="table">
  <% @node.table.each do |row| %>
    <tr>
      <th><%= row[1]['head'] %></th> <td><%= row[1]['tail'] %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

And my node.js file contains the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#header').append('Script loaded')
  var newIndex = 0
  $('#add_table_row').click(function(){
    $('.sidebar_img').append('onclick event activated')
    var prevIndex = newIndex
    var prevRow = $('#node_table_row')
    newIndex = newIndex + 1
    var newRow = prevRow.clone(true).attr('id', 'node_table_row_'+newIndex)
    newRow.find('#node_table_row_head').attr({ id: 'node_table_row_head_'+newIndex, name: 'node[table][row'+newIndex+'][head]'})
    newRow.find('#node_table_row_tail').attr({ id: 'node_table_row_tail_'+newIndex, name: 'node[table][row'+newIndex+'][tail]'})
    newRow.after(prevRow)
  });
});
```

When I click the "add row" button, I get my confirmation that the onclick event has been recognized, but the forms are not appended. Am I approaching this entirely the wrong way? It seems like there would be a simpler way to go about this.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the jQuery insertAfter() method? use jQuery to select the table then use .children().insertAfter(newRow);

Comment: Editing the table happens on a different page than the one on which the table is rendered.

Comment: Ok, just to make sure I understand what is happening here, the edit page will send a query to a database and then the table will be pulled from the databse, correct?

Comment: The edit page will contain a form with a separate field for each row of the table's header and content, which, yes, will eventually be filled with the table's existing contents. I haven't gotten that far yet, though. Right now, I'm just trying to create the fields so that they can update the database based on input. The tricky part is generating those via jQuery.

Comment: Are you having trouble figuring out which selector to use or are you having trouble figuring out which jQuery function to call?